# Contramot or contramote

Tags: spelling

There is a term in Russian (the noun контрамот) made up of Latin соntra (against) and motio (motion). Means something like "moving in the opposite direction". How would it be spelled in English - соntramot or соntramote?

Comment: How would it be spelt if imported as a loanword, or how would it be spelt as a Russian word transliterated into the Roman alphabet in order to be mentioned in English text?

Comment: Neither. What I mean is: how the ENGLISH  word would  be spelt which is obtained as a sum of "соntra" and "motio"?

Comment: I would spell that word *U-P-S-T-R-E-A-M*

Answer (score 1):

The relevant analogues would be "promote" (v.), "promotion" (n.), "remote" (adj.), "emote" (v.), "emotion" (n.), "motion" (n.).  Not all come directly from Latin, and "emote" is a backformation.  Still, these would indicate that if we wanted to borrow the Latin term into English, it would be "contramote" as a verb, "contramotion" as a noun.

Note: The OED contains "countermove" (verb: rare) and "countermotion" (noun) with the same meaning of moving in the opposite direction.

Comment: I feel that  "contramotion" means the PROCESS. What about a moving OBJECT?

Comment: Normally a "motion" is a process rather than an object, so I agree that a "contramotion" would probably be a process.  That said, a "motion" can also be a resolution for discussion, and a countermotion could be a resolution opposing the original motion.  But I find it hard to imagine "contramotion" or "countermotion" as a noun denoting a physical object.

Comment: So, what would be the word for an object?

Comment: @Serguei: Has your question morphed into *Is there a single English word that means 'an object moving in a direction counter to something?*  Is this question "academic" (how would we create such a word if it does not already exist?) or practical? If the latter, perhaps you could provide an example sentence and ask how the idea would be expressed idiomatically in English.

Comment: It is a practical  question (how should one spell the word with the given meaning and etymology?)

Comment: It's hard to say whether it's likely that the word "contramote" would be chosen for this purpose (a noun denoting a moving object).  But if it were chosen, I feel confident that it would be spelt with a final "e" - not as "contramot".